# Receive JSON list from http://www.autorenlexikon.lu

Tags: java, javascript, json, web-services

I want to read a JSON list from a webservice with Java. The webservice returns a list of authors from luxemburg, e.g. sorted by the year. That's the web-site:

http://www.autorenlexikon.lu/page/periods/1919-1945/1/1/DEU/index.html

So far, I know that I can receive a JSON document with a request like this:

```
http://www.autorenlexikon.lu/mmp/json.document_list/DEU/0?search_since=1919&search_until=1945
```

But I only get the first 20 entries. **How can I get the next 20 entries?** I think the solution is in the JavaScript-code of the web-site, but I am pretty new in JavaScript (also in JSON).

EDIT:

- There isn't any official API.
- I have already tried:

  http://www.autorenlexikon.lu/mmp/json.document_list/DEU/0?pageSize=1000&search_since=1919&search_until=1945

  http://www.autorenlexikon.lu/mmp/json.document_list/DEU/0?page_Size=1000&search_since=1919&search_until=1945

  ...and many more. Who does the JavaScript-code receive all entries? Couldn't I copy this mechanism?

Comment: You need to find the documentation to see how pagination works for this particular service because that is something entirely service-specific.

Comment: Please clarify: JavaScript or Java?

Comment: There isn't any official documentation. I hoped, somebody could read the solution out of the JavaScript code. I mean, this code does exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: I want to read the JSON list with Java. But I think the solution of my problem is in the JavaScript-code of the web-site, because it uses the web-service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check their API and look for a parameter that let's you define the page or the range of results you want to get.

*Edit* Seems like you'd have to make a POST request and add the start index as well as the page size as post parameters. For more information see @matthijs koevoets' answer.

Comment: oh!!! it works. When I type http://www.autorenlexikon.lu/mmp/json.document_list/DEU/0?results=100&startIndex=0 it works. But when I only type http://www.autorenlexikon.lu/mmp/json.document_list/DEU/0?results=100 it doesn't work. No matter. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the Webservice has been coded. Nothing to do with JSON specifically. From the results you can see it says

```
"pageSize":20,
```

You just have to figure out how to call the Web service with a page size. It may not allow you to query it with a different page size. That's up to the Web service API coded by their developers

Comment: You don't want to provide a different _page size_ but another _page_ or _start index_.

Comment: Exactly. But how can I use it in the web-request? I have already tried "pageSize=100", "page_size=100" and so on. Nothing worked.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig That depends on the implementation of that service, i.e. how exactly the parameter is spelled. You'd have to get that from their API description. Where did you the `search_since` and `search_until` parameters from?

Comment: @Thomas: Unfortunatelly, there isn't any official API. The the search_since and search_until parameters are from the JavaScript-code of the web-site. But I couldn't read out how it sets the page size.

Comment: I had a play with some obvious guesses (i.e. pageSize=30, page_size=30, size=30) but no joy. It would be best to email the web site owner and ask them if it is supported.

Answer (score 1):

their service seems to accept POST parameters only: sort=year&dir=asc&startIndex=0&results=100

Comment: yes. there is also search_locations and search_genre. but I can't find any parameter for the page size. No matter how I spell it.

Comment: @Thomas page size is the `results` parameter

Comment: Realy? How does it work? I tried http://www.autorenlexikon.lu/mmp/json.document_list/DEU/0?results=100. But the result is the same as without "results=100".

Comment: @Thomas Any parameters added to the url are _GET_ parameters. You have to issue a _POST_ request. Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html